# How do I dynamically style a cell based on user-input using openpyxl.kinda like highlighting current user location in leaderboard

Tags: python, openpyxl, styling, leaderboard

I'm creating a leaderboard using openpyxl to write. But I just can't get current player to be colored using the style method.
Here's what I did.
After importing all necessary libraries

```
username = input(': ')

for row in sheet.values:
 for value in row:
  If value == username:
   sheet.value.font = Font(color=colors.Blue)
```

It doesn't do anything. Please someone help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are extracting the *values* of the sheet and looping through them, and then expecting to be able to reference the sheet. This won't work. If you want to reference the sheet, you work with sheet references.

(Note this isn't the cleanest way to do it)

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Color, Font, colors

username = input(': ')

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

for current_row in sheet:
    for current_column in current_row:
        if current_column.value == username:
            current_column.font = Font(color=colors.BLUE)

wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks so much. But it still isn't reflecting on my sheet when I open it in Excel. Wish I could send a screenshot

Comment: You can send a screenshot. Take the picture and upload the image to your question as an edit. The code works on my machine which suggests something else is wrong e.g. make sure the name matches exactly and there are not any trailing space (a common problem with validating in Excel)

Comment: (I should add that if any sensitive information is in the screenshot, you should use Paint to put some black lines over the important data) Or you could practice with a sample Excel file.